# In Terminal EACCES error during the angler cli installation?

Tags: angular, npm-install

When I try to install angular/cli using terminal command. "[sudo] nam install -g @angular/cli" after

```html
gyp verb tmpdir == cwd automatically will remove dev files after to save disk space
gyp verb command install [ '8.9.4' ]
gyp verb install input version string "8.9.4"
gyp verb install installing version: 8.9.4
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version not already installed, continuing with install 8.9.4
gyp verb ensuring nodedir is created /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp/8.9.4
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp/8.9.4"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp"
```

as you can see last Line WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp/8.9.4"

after that I checked  dir using "ls -la /usr/local/bin"

```html
Niteshs-Air:~ niteshwaghmare$ ls -la /usr/local
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  8 root  wheel  256 Mar  2 22:01 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 9 root  wheel  288 Dec  2 01:02 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    0 Mar  1 21:32 .com.apple.installer.keep
drwxr-xr-x  8 root  wheel  256 Mar  3 20:38 bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel   64 Mar  2 22:01 etc
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel   96 Jan  3 08:23 include
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  128 Jan  3 08:23 lib
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel  160 Jan  3 08:23 share
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. What causes this issue I do not know. As it seems to be a permissions issue, I temporarily changed the permissions for the @angular folder in /usr/local/lib/node_modules:

1. sudo chmod 777 @angular (change the permissions for wider access)
2. sudo npm install -g @angular/cli (install the Angular CLI)
3. sudo chmod 755 @angular (change the permissions back the way they were)

This worked for me